# Whirpool ice maker overflow

Tags: refrigerator, freezing, ice-maker

The icemaker in my whirlpool Wsf26c2exf01 is overflowing. The water reaches the icemaker fine but it spills into the ice bucket and leaks out of the unit. The only way to stop it is turning off the water at the pipe, it continues to flow even with the icemaker switch in off position, it will flow with the door closed(door closed switch compressed). I would appreciate any suggestions on what to test for next or how to go about completing a repair.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Here is a link to the video
https://youtu.be/n24eGizrAlw

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the water controll solenoid has something stuck in it allowing the water to flow. These solenoids are normally closed and require power to open. It is possible a small piece of pipe scale is holding the valve open. It is also possible that there is a failed component on the controll board but that is doubtful because it is running with the switch in the off position. With the unit unplugged and the water turned off dissembling the valve and cleaning it may clear up the problem but a new solenoid valve may be required.